# I want to go to grad school but don't have personal relationships with any of my online professors. What do I do about the LOR requirements?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter, online-learning, online-degree

I am an undergraduate student expecting to graduate next spring, but i've attended online classes for the past 2-3 years and don't normally have much contact with my online professors. I want to apply for a masters program, but probably not for another year. When I apply next year, I'm afraid i'll have no one to ask for a LOR. I feel like I am supposed to ask for letters of recommendation from professors who know me well, but I don't have anyone who fits that bill. I'm afraid that if I ask for a LOR from a past professor, especially in a year from now, they'll respond negatively to an ask from a random student they don't even remember.

I don't know how I could've (or if I should've) tried to foster relationships with professors online. I am the kind of student to just read the syllabus and do the work. I don't often have questions to contact the professor with and I understand the coursework just fine on my own. I have had especially limited contact because online professors ask you to try every other resource before e-mailing them.

Can anyone give me advice about how to meet the LOR requirements for graduate program application?

Comment: Can you apply to the same place as undergrad? For example ASU has engineering BS and MS online and will be happy to admit you to online MS after completing BS but it won't be funded. In fact most distance MS programs are pretty lax about admission if they aren't funding you.

Comment: My sympathies. When on-line course instructors say "try every other resource before emailing them", you are being short-changed... The economics of purely-on-line "campuses" and so on coerces this, sadly, and short-changes students who want to go to grad school. The _quality_ of on-line instruction is _NOT_ My necessarily that barren... but the pre-Covid model was very stingy.

Comment: @FourierFlux I am at ASU for my undergrad actually but I really want to do an in-person MS program.

Comment: Hmm, Im not sure. You could ask your professors about in person MS programs that they have experience with. ASU is pretty well known so your degree isn't a disadvantage.